# Questions on boolean intialization

Tags: java, boolean

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class array {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            String names[] = {"John", "Mary", "Peter"};
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter name: ");
            String nameEntered = myScanner.nextLine();
            boolean nameFound = false;
            for (String i : names)
            {
                if(nameEntered.equals(i))
                    nameFound = true;
            }

            if(nameFound)
                System.out.println(nameEntered + " is a common name.");
            else
                System.out.println(nameEntered + " is not a common name.");
        }
}
```

How does boolean work exactly? I heard that if you don't initialize it, its default would be false anyway? So why can't I simply do boolean nameFound; instead of boolean nameFound = false; ? I'm still newish to coding

Comment: That is true for member variables, not local variables. Local variables have to be *definitely assigned* before use.

Comment: "I heard that if you don't initialize it, its default would be false anyway"—You heard wrong. Default initialization applies to fields, not to local variables. You have to give a local variable a value before you can use it.

Comment: Btw, an easier way would be `boolean nameFound = Arrays.asList(names).contains(nameEntered);`.

Comment: It is not good practice to rely on default values (the reader then has to **know** what the default is), or `static` fields (globals are bad). That being said: `private static boolean nameFound;` outside of `main` **would** default to `false`.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch What about the case of types deriving from `Object`? It doesn't seem productive to explicitly state it in every direct subtype of `Object`, even though it's a default which has caused beginners issues ("*why does my object have a `notify()` method?*"). I agree in theory, it's best to be explicit, I just can't imagine this being practiced. Do you explicitly assign all values, even if it's equivalent to the default? Or are there specific cases which you believe should be excluded? Don't want to get off-topic, but that was a pretty strong statement.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I'm not certain which statement you find so risible, or why we're now talking about `Object`. My ***intent*** was only to say `private static boolean nameFound = false;` is easier to read than `private static boolean nameFound;` - because the first is explicitly `false`. While the second makes someone pause and decide what value `nameFound` has. Nothing more than that. And it was really intended as a "what I'm about to show you is not 'my recommendation' just something you can do". (I did say "default values" not just "defaults").

Comment: @ElliotFrisch I was curious. You have more experience than I do, and you were suggesting that default values shouldn't be relied on. To me, it seemed to fall under the same category as "explicit private enum constructors" or extending `Object`. I could be 100% wrong. "Don't rely on default values" would indirectly solve his issue, wasn't saying it was a bad statement, I agree to the reasoning of not using defaults. Was wondering if assigning defaults in the field was something an experienced dev (you) practice in production. But I'll stop it here, getting off-topic.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I **certainly** try to. I'll simply refer you to this [blog post from Jeff Atwood](https://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-for-violent-psychopaths/).